# Where to find the Ethereum wallet contract?

Tags: solidity, mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

In Mist wallet, there are WALLET CONTRACTS. I can not find it in Github and could somebody tell me the location of the sol code?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ethereum/mist is the repository for Mist and the Ethereum Wallet.

The [Wallet-README.txt](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/develop/Wallet-README.txt) indicates:

> The wallet code can be found at
>   https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet

Inside that repository, is a Wallet.sol, the last file here:

[image]

Comment: ETH, Nice catch.

Comment: but where is the WALLET CONTRACTS (sol files)?

Comment: I added a screenshot for you: Wallet.sol is the last file.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to the community! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the big checkbox.